# How to get the value of a Java variable to javascript in JavaFX webView?

Tags: java, javascript, xpath, webview, javafx

I'm using the below code, to communicate between Java and Javascript objects.

```
find.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
        JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
        window.setMember("clickController", new WebViewController());

        webEngine.executeScript("var element = document.evaluate(clickController.getXpath(), document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;"+
                    "clickController.printId(element, \"sad\");"+
                    "if (element != null) {"+
                    "element.style.backgroundColor = \"#FDFF47\";"+
                    "}");
    }
});


public void printId(Object object, String returnValue) {
    //              System.out.println(returnValue);
    AttributesModel model = new AttributesModel();
    if (org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLElement.class.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass())) {
        org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLElement it = (org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLElement) object;
        model.setId(it.getId());
        model.setValue(it.getAttribute("value"));
        model.setName(it.getAttribute("name"));
        model.setCls(it.getClassName());
        model.setLink(it.getTextContent());
        model.setTag(it.getTagName());
        model.setXpath(returnValue);
    }
    System.out.println(model.toString());
}

public String getXpath(){
    return xpath.getText();
}
```

`printId()` and `getXpath()` methods are enclosed within a class called `WebViewController`. I'm clicking on a "Find" button upon which the remaining code gets executed.
`clickController.printId()` is working properly. The problem is with `clickController.getXpath()`. I'm not able to get the xpath value using that. When I specify xPath directly, it works. But I will be getting Xpath from the user during runtime. So I need to call `getXpath()` method. When executed, the browser crashes. Where am I going wrong? Please help.

Comment: Is `WebViewController` a controller class (i.e. associated to an FXML file)? If so, instantiating a `new WebViewController()` seems like the wrong thing to do. What is `xpath` in `WebViewController` and how is it initialized?

Comment: Yes it is a controller associated with FXML. 
I will try creating a new class and use new Class(). xpath in WebViewController is a textfield in FXML.

Comment: If `xpath` is injected by FXML, and you create the controller instance yourself with `new WebViewController()`, then `xpath` will be `null` and you'll get a `NullPointerException`. You need to retrieve the controller instance from the `FXMLLoader`, not create a new one.

Comment: I got it @James_D. I worked it out. Thanks :)