# How to get Elements from Webview Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, webview, desktop-application

I have an application where I give to values to a website via link and then the application shows me a map and draws a polyline between the given values. So what I need now is that I have to extract specific values from the Webview so in this post [How to get the value of a Java variable to javascript in JavaFX webView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30616131/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-java-variable-to-javascript-in-javafx-webview) they use getDocument but i did not understand the code and thats why I couldnt use it very well for me. Can someone maybe help me out?

code for showing map:

```
@FXML
void openHtmlfile(ActionEvent event) {
    WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
    webEngine.javaScriptEnabledProperty().set(true);
    webEngine.load("https://www.luftlinie.org/"+ fromTextField.getText() +"/"+ toTextField.getText());
    ;
}
```

Method to give the values from the texfields and fill them

```
void fillFields(ActionEvent event) {

    String startAirport = null;
    String targetAirport = null;
    String startCountry = null;
    String targetCountry = null;

    Statement airport;
    try {
        airport = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet MyRsAirport = airport.executeQuery("select * from fluglinie where ID =\""
                + idFlightRoute.getValue() + "\" AND fluggesellschaft =\"" + fluggesellschaft + "\"");
        while (MyRsAirport.next()) {

            startAirport = MyRsAirport.getString("startFlughafen");

            targetAirport = MyRsAirport.getString("zielFlughafen");

        }
        Statement country;
        country = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet MyRsCountry = country.executeQuery("select * from flughaefen");
        while (MyRsCountry.next()) {

            if (MyRsCountry.getString("name").equals(startAirport)) {
                startCountry = MyRsCountry.getString("country");
            } else if (MyRsCountry.getString("name").equals(targetAirport)) {
                targetCountry = MyRsCountry.getString("country");
            }

        }

        fromTextField.setText(startAirport + ", " + startCountry); 
        toTextField.setText(targetAirport + ", " + targetCountry); 

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and what I want to do now is for example there is a distance calculated between these two points and I want to extract it. I know I have to use the id of the specific html element but how do I show it in java?

Comment: You probably want `webEngine.getDocument().getElementById(id).getTextContent()`.  You will of course have to wait listen for the WebEngine’s [loadWorker](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#getLoadWorker%28%29) to reach a finished state, first.

Comment: hi do you maybe have an simple example of this? the post I had posted used an Element with it but it does not work gives me an error.. I am a novice so i kind of need an example to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Always remember that the official documentation is your friend.

First, you need to wait for the page to full load.  You do this by observing the WebEngine’s [load worker](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#getLoadWorker%28%29), which will have a state of [SUCCEEDED](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Worker.State.html#SUCCEEDED) when it is finished.  This approach is described in detail in [the WebEngine documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html).

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
    (o, oldState, newState) -> {
        if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            // ...
        }
    });
webEngine.load("https://www.luftlinie.org/"+ fromTextField.getText() +"/"+ toTextField.getText());
```

**Important:** You must add the loadWorker listener *before* loading the page.

Once the load worker completes successfully, you can safely access the WebEngine’s [document](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#getDocument%28%29), which contains the entre loaded page.  You can search for an element with a particular ID using the conveniently named [getElementById](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementById%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
webEngine.getDocument().getElementById("some-page-specific-ID")
```

Exactly what string you should pass will depend on the page.  It is up to you to examine the page’s source and discover the `id` of the element whose content you want.

If the element does not have an `id` attribute, you will have to rely on the document’s structure and use [XPath](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) to find the HTML element of interest.  A tutorial on the use of XPath would make this answer too large, but you can learn about it yourself by reading [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/).  Reading it will require a working knowledge of XML.

Once you have found the element, extracting the information from it will depend on what kind of element it is.  If it’s just text, you can use the element’s [getTextContent()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29) method.

So, the overall code would look something like this:

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
    (o, oldState, newState) -> {
        if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
            Element element = doc.getElementById("some-page-specific-ID");
            String value = element.getTextContent();

            // Display value ...
        }
    });
webEngine.load("https://www.luftlinie.org/"+ fromTextField.getText() +"/"+ toTextField.getText());
```